# Adjust R user settings to allow for assigning .popath

Tags: r

I am trying to install a package and am getting an unusual (to me) error:

```
devtools::install_github("MikkoVihtakari/ggOceanMapsData")    

Error in assign(".popath", popath, .BaseNamespaceEnv) : 
cannot change value of locked binding for '.popath'
Calls: local ... eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> eval -> eval -> assign
```

I have mucked around with the R_USER, R_LIBS, HOME, etc settings to try and get R and knitr to behave. I have been successful there, but now this error. Any thoughts on what this means and how to fix the issue would be welcomed.

I found a similar post, that indicated clearing the R history worked to solve the issue, but that did not for me.

It appears to be associated with the base package and ".popath is a variable created at startup which records where the translations package in use is."

Session info:

```
 R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
 Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
 Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
```